# Android fragment performance

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 quite similar fragments with some differences in layout, but they have the same java class. I need to switch them very often, but they have a lot of heavy views and animations inside. I see two ways to do it.

1. Show some views and hide some when fragment need to be changed but it will be the same fragment.
2. Have two different fragment layout files and switch them fully recreating.

Second approach looks more logical to me, but what about performance?

Comment: do you load any data or just create these views ? is there any larger logic behind these fragments ? 1. create layout in constraint layout, sort views into `Groups` and control the visibility of the group depending on your need. 2. You have to remember about back stack. You can use navigation component for moving around fragments.

Comment: For me 2nd is right way, create 2 separate fragments and use them when you need base on your constraints. it's will increase performance

Comment: If you want to follow the SOLID principle it's better to separate your fragments into individual classes to separate your concerns and avoid multi-purpose class.

Answer (score 0):

To have optimal performance, create sperate Fragments with each class then use jetpack Viewmodel to share state and data between the fragments. Also, create layout template and use include to prevent code duplication.

For further reading on jetpack viewmodel visit this link
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel